# tensorflow lite Raspberry Pi classification

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite

as a part of my school project, I created a tensorflow lite model to classify if the eye is open or close. I cross-compile an executable on my PC to run the tensorflow lite file in my raspberry pi. However, when I run my executable on some of the images, I got an unwanted classification. Any ideas, why this could have happen?

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external link.

Comment: Please insert the output as text. It will **make it readable and searchable**.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your model is trained to produce more output labels than just open or closed.  Did you train your model to produce only two outputs: Open and Closed?